# How do I prove that $E(f(X)) \leq E(f(Y))$ for $f$ increasing and $X$ and $Y$ multivariate Bernoulli?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose $f:\{0,1\}^n \to R$ is an increasing function (we say that $x \leq y$ for $x,y \in \{0,1\}^n$ if $x_i \leq y_i$ for all $i$.) Let $X_p = (X_1, ..., X_n)$ be a random vector such that $X_i \text{~ Bernoulli}(p)$, with the $X_i$ independent.

Suppose $0 \leq p_1 \leq p_2 \leq 1$, I am trying to prove that $$E(f(X_{p_1})) \leq E(f(X_{p_2}))$$

Writing this explicitly, we must show that $$E(f(X_{p_1})) = \sum_{x \in \{0,1\}^n} f(x)P(X_{p_1}=x) \leq \sum_{x \in \{0,1\}^n} f(x)P(X_{p_2}=x) = E(f(X_{p_2}))$$

I know that $f(x) \leq f(y) \iff x \leq y \iff x_1 + ... + x_n \leq y_1 + ... + y_n$, but I couldn't figure out how to relate the original expectations to anything useful by comparing the probabilities of the sums of the vector entries.

I've also tried writing - 
$$\sum_{x \in \{0,1\}^n} f(x)P(X_{p_1}=x) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} f_k  {n \choose k}p_1^k(1-p_1)^{n-k}$$ (where $f_k = f(x)$, for any $x \in \{0,1\}^n$ with $x_1 + ... + x_n = k$) and trying to apply Chebyshev's sum inequality, but I couldn't get anywhere with that either.

Informally speaking, I understand that if there is more probability mass on the vectors with more 1's, then the expectation should increase, but I can't figure out how to prove this explicitly.

Lastly, how does the above relate to the FKG inequality?

If I could have a small hint to point me in the right direction, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Find a coupling between $X_{p_1}$ and $X_{p_2}$, that is a joint distribution of the 2 vectors is such that the margins are  iid Bernoulli with $p_1$ and $p_2$ respectively, in such a way that $X_{p_1}\le X_{p_2}$ with probability 1.

Comment: @kimchilover Would you mind expanding on this a little more? I'm having trouble figuring out what to do. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Start with  $n=1$ to keep things simple.  Let $U$ be uniform on $[0,1]$, let $X=1$ if $U<p_1$, otherwise $0$.  Let $Y=1$ if $U<p_2$, otherwise $0$.   But $X$ is Bernoulli $p_1$ and $Y$ is Bernoulli $p_2$. And,  no matter what $U$ is, we have $X\le Y$.  So, with probability 1, $X\le Y$.  Since $f$ is increasing, $f(X)\le f(Y)$ with probability 1, and hence $Ef(X)\le Ef(Y)$.  The trick is that $X$ and $Y$ are *not* independent, but have the correct margins.

For $n>1$ let $U_1,\dots,U_n$ be iid uniforms on $[0,1]$.  Use them to construct a vector $(X_1,\dots,U_n)$ of iid Bernoullis $p_1$, and a vector of iid Bernoullis $p_2$ $(Y_1,\dots,Y_n)$, for which with probability 1, $X_i\le Y_i$, and proceed as above.